# CakePHPでテーブル結合後、取得した要素のソーティング方法。

Tags: php, cakephp

以下の質問者です。
[CakePHPのページネーション処理で検索条件が想定どおりに反映されない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12770/cakephp%E3%81%AE%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8D%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E5%87%A6%E7%90%86%E3%81%A7%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E3%81%8C%E6%83%B3%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%A9%E3%81%8A%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AB%E5%8F%8D%E6%98%A0%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/)

こちらのコントローラの記述で無事に変数$eventsの一覧は取得する事ができました。
さらに発展させて、他のテーブルからデータを結合したのですが、今度はそちらのソーティングがうまくいかなくなってしまいました。

```
// ページネーション
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 20,
    'paramType' => 'querystring',
    'conditions'=> array('Event.id' => $event_ids),
);
$events = $this->paginate('Event');

//別のEvents_calendarに登録されているstartdateを結合
　　 for($i=0; $i<count($events); $i++) {
        // カレンダーを結合
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Events_calendar.event_id' => $events[$i]['Event']['id']));
        $events_calendar = $this->Events_calendar->find('first', $options);

        if(isset($events_calendar['Events_calendar']['startdate'])) {
            $events[$i]['Event']['startdate'] = $events_calendar['Events_calendar']['startdate'];

            // startdateを年月日に分ける
            // 2015-05-03 00:00:00
            $tmp1_created = array();
            $tmp2_created = array();
            $tmp1_created = split(' ', $events[$i]['Event']['startdate']);
            $tmp2_created = split('-', $tmp1_created[0]);
            // イベント日をMM/DDに変更
            $event_date[$i] = $tmp2_created[1].'/'.$tmp2_created[2];
            $events[$i]['Event']['event_date'] = $event_date[$i];

        } else {
            $events[$i]['Event']['startdate'] = null;
        }
    }
    $this->set('events', $evetns);
```

上記で取得した$eventsを`event_date`で日付が近い順にソーティングしたいのですが、想定している結果に繋がりません、、、、、

何か良い方法をご存知の方ご教授願います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この場合、2つの解決方法が考えられます。

## 1. Hash::sortを利用する

とりあえずで対処したいならこちらで。

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::sort

```
$evetns = Hash::sort($evetns, '{n}.Event.startdate', 'asc');
```

を、Viewへ変数をセットする前に入れておきます。

## 2. アソシエーション(hasOne)を利用する

EventとEvents_calendarが同一DBに存在する場合は、若干手間ですがこちらの方がより良い実装になります。

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasone

Eventモデルに対して、Events_calendarをhasOneで紐付けます。
（`Events_calendar`というモデル名がすごく気になるのですが、ここではそのままで行きます。。

```
<?php

class Event extends Model {
    // ... (snip)
    public $hasOne = [
        'Events_calendar' => [
            'className' => 'Events_calendar',
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
        ],
    ];
    // ... (snip)
}
```

コントローラ側は以下のように書きます。

```
// ページネーション
$this->paginate = [
    'limit' => 20,
    'paramType' => 'querystring',
    'conditions'=> ['Event.id' => $event_ids],
    'order' => ['Events_calendar.startdate' => 'asc'],
    'recursive' => 1,
];
$events = $this->paginate('Event');
```

これで 'Events_calendar.startdate' の昇順に、

```
[
   ['Event' => [ ... ], 'Events_calendar' => [ ... ]],
   ['Event' => [ ... ], 'Events_calendar' => [ ... ]],
]
```

のような形でデータを取得できます。

補足:
`'event_date'` の生成については、View側で行うべき事象だと考えます。またフォーマットの方法については、`CakeTime::format()`か`TimeHelper::format()`を利用するとよいでしょう。

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime::format

```
CakeTime::format($events[$i]['Events_calendar']['startdate'], '%m/%d');
```

Comment: 大変ご丁寧に解説頂きまして有難うございました。

一つ追加で質問させていただきます。

とりあえずで`Hash::sort()`を`$events`を`set`する直前に置いたのですが、各ページは日付ごとにソーティングされているのですが、$events全体としてソーティングしてからページングが一番望ましい出力なのですがこれを実現するにはどのような順番で記述するのが望ましいのでしょうか？

Comment: その場合は 2 の方法で、アソシエーションを組んでからページングを行ってください。

Comment: 2の方法を試したところ、当に想定しておりました結果を得ることが出来、新しくアソシエーション、CakeTimeに関する知識も広がり大変勉強になりました。誠に有難うございました。